# make two div equal height with basic css only on window resizing don't change arrangement

Tags: html, css

hello everyone I want two div's side by side and make them equal height with unequal content. When resizing window it should not change arrangement and it should not grow or shrink unequally

```html
 <div id="o1" style="border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
                background-color:#eeeeee;
                float: left;
                padding:3px;
                border: thin solid black;
                width: 20px;
                border-right:none;">A.</div>

<div style="border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
                float: left;
                padding:3px;
                border: thin solid black;
                width: 200px;" id="i1">Mumbai</div>

<span style="clear:both;" id="i1a"></span><br/><br/>

<div id="o2" style="border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
                background-color:#eeeeee;
                float: left;
                padding:3px;
                border: thin solid black;
                width: 20px;
                border-right:none;">B.</div>

<div style="border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
                float: left;
                padding:3px;
                border: thin solid black;
                width: 200px;" id="i2">Delhi</div>

<span style="clear:both;" id="i2a"></span><br/><br/>

<div id="o3" style="border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px; 
                background-color:#eeeeee; 
                float: left; 
                padding:3px; 
                border: thin solid black; 
                width: 20px; 
                border-right:none;">C.</div>

<div style="border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px; 
                float: left; 
                padding:3px; 
                border: thin solid black; 
                width: 200px;" id="i3">Mumbai</div>

<span style="clear:both;" id="i3a"></span><br/><br/>

<div id="o4" style="border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px; 
                background-color:#eeeeee; 
                float: left; 
                padding:3px; 
                border: thin solid black; 
                width: 20px; 
                border-right:none;">D.</div>

<div style="border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
                float: left; padding:3px;
                border: thin solid black;
                width: 200px;" id="i4" >Kanpur</div>

<span style="clear:both;" id="i4a"></span><br/><br/>

<div id="as1" style="float: left; 
                padding:3px; 
                border: 1px solid black; 
                display:none;">Ans: Delhi</div>
```

This is the output:

[image]

But when I resize window its content arrangement get changed. I want when window resize in any device its content grow or shrink equally with same formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Use % instead of pixels on your width.This scales your page size depending on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your code is quite messy and uses inline-styles.</s>

I've cleaned it up.

You can give `.item` a fix width with `px` or a fluid width with `%`. The `white-space: pre` and `overflow: hidden` makes sure the text doesn't jump to the next line.

Updated based on comment.

```css
.item {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 220px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 32px;
}

.item span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"><span>A.</span> Mumbai with more text for the next line</div>
<div class="item"><span>B.</span> Delhi</div>
<div class="item"><span>C.</span> Mumbai</div>
<div class="item"><span>D.</span> Kanpur</div>
```

Comment: not working as expected, if content size increase its height not grow. I want fixed width but when content size increase it height increase and also when window resize it design should not mashup.

Comment: @NEERAJSingh Ah, okay, that wasn't clear to me in your question. No problem tho, I've updated the answer.

Comment: It's work for latest browser please update it for IE8 also it'look like https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7gqt3Eoeh-mZ1JVYW1JNlhRWjQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try this ! this should do the trick!
with pure css and html this is what you can do!

other way can be using a table!

https://jsfiddle.net/7ae2eLdg/

```html
<div id="o2" style="border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
                background-color:#eeeeee;
                float: left;
                padding:3px;
                border: thin solid black;
                width: 200px;
               "><span style="border-right: thin solid black; padding:4px;">B</span> Ahmedabad</div>



<span style="clear:both;" id="i1a"></span><br/><br/>


<div id="o2" style="border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
                background-color:#eeeeee;
                float: left;
                padding:3px;
                border: thin solid black;
                width: 200px;
               "><span style="border-right: thin solid black; padding:4px;">B</span> Delhi</div>





<span style="clear:both;" id="i2a"></span><br/><br/>

<div id="o2" style="border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
                background-color:#eeeeee;
                float: left;
                padding:3px;
                border: thin solid black;
                width: 200px;
               "><span style="border-right: thin solid black; padding:4px;">B</span> Kanpur</div>



<span style="clear:both;" id="i3a"></span><br/><br/>

<div id="o2" style="border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
                background-color:#eeeeee;
                float: left;
                padding:3px;
                border: thin solid black;
                width: 200px;
               "><span style="border-right: thin solid black; padding:4px;">B</span> Mumbai</div>

<span style="clear:both;" id="i4a"></span><br/><br/>
```